iOS Push Notifications Not Working After Changing Bundle ID and Firebase Project
Issue :
I recently changed the Bundle ID of my Flutter app and created a new Firebase project to match the updated Bundle ID. While push notifications are working perfectly on Android, they are not working on iOS.
Steps Taken:
Created a new Firebase project and added the new iOS app with the updated Bundle ID.
Downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file and replaced it in my Flutter project.
Generated new APNs Authentication Key in the Apple Developer Console and uploaded it to Firebase.
Verified the following:
The Bundle ID in Xcode matches the one in the Firebase project.
The provisioning profiles and certificates are correctly configured in Xcode.
The APNs key is correctly linked to the new Firebase project.
Enabled Push Notifications and Background Modes (Remote Notifications) in Xcode.
Observations:
Android push notifications are working without issues.
On iOS, the app doesn't receive any push notifications.
What I’ve Tried
Double-checked the APNs key and re-uploaded it to Firebase.
Verified that the app is registered for push notifications in the device settings.
Tested notifications via Firebase Console and backend server.
Looked through Xcode logs, but didn't see any errors related to notifications.
Questions:
Are there additional steps I might have missed when reconfiguring Firebase for iOS after changing the Bundle ID?
How can I debug this issue further to identify why notifications are not being received on iOS?Issue :
I recently changed the Bundle ID of my Flutter app and created a new Firebase project to match the updated Bundle ID. While push notifications are working perfectly on Android, they are not working on iOS.
Update:
I've tried sending a push notification from Apple Push Notification console and it was received in the device.
Delivery report for that notification
Background modes are enabled as well

Update the Bundle ID everywhere (Firebase console, Xcode, Apple Developer portal).
Replace GoogleService-Info.plist with the new one.
Re-check APNs Auth Key and entitlements for your new Bundle ID.
Verify the provisioning profile includes push notification capability.
Print/log the APNs device token.
Check Xcode logs for APNs registration failures.
Test push directly via curl (APNs) to isolate if the issue is with APNs or Firebase.
Enable Firebase debug logs to confirm the token is reaching FCM.
Post results of above did not help.

I've tried these steps and  have few updates. Added them to the question. Please take a look.
